# How can I make jQuery UI Dialogs open in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, window, parent

I have a web application that has a number of dialogs that pop up that contain controls that modify various attributes of a data model. I'm currently displaying these dialogs using a jQuery UI Dialog. A new requirement is that users want to be able to pop the dialog out of the current window. I can create a new window containing the controls like this:

```
function OpenSidebarInNewWindow(){
    var DialogName = 'AdditionalDetailsDiv';
    var OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "height=250, width=250,toolbar=no,scrollbars="+scroll+",menubar=no");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<HTML>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<TITLE>" + DialogName + "</TITLE>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("<BODY>");
    OpenWindow.document.write(window.document.getElementById(DialogName).innerHTML);
    OpenWindow.document.write("</BODY>");
    OpenWindow.document.write("</HTML>");

}
```

But the problem is any event handlers I have on those controls are scoped to the parent window's "window". Is there any way that I can modify the Function.prototype or something on the child page to try to call window.opener[function] if window[function] doesn't exist?

If not, can anyone suggest a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: you can check if function exist in current window and call another one

Comment: Right, but would I have to do that for every function individually used in the child window, or is there some way to globally do this?

Comment: create another page that contains necessary scripts and css...then can use postMessage API to communicate between the 2 windows

Comment: So the whole thing I'm trying to avoid is needing to maintain two different versions of my code (for all the control event handlers), one for the embedded div and one for the new window. It's sort of sounding like there's no way around that.